# validating image in laravel partially working

Tags: php, laravel

I knew this question may sound duplicate but am just in a mess.

Iam new to Laravel. coming from php background.
I am using the code below to validate image in laravel 5.7.8. it does validation by checking the file extension name, size etc. Now I want to check the mimetype as a way securing the file upload hence the code

```
        $rules= [
             'file' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif'
        ];
        $x = $request->all();
        $validator=Validator::make($x, $rules);
        if ($validator->passes()){

 Session::flash('message','File Uploads successful.');
        }else{
         Session::flash('message','Invalid File type .');

        }
```

My problem is that its not returning error message eg **Invalid File type** when an invalid file is uploaded.

Below is how I added it to my main controller. All other checking are okay.  I just want the code to print **Invalid File type** whenever a file that is not image is being uploaded

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Session;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PictureController extends Controller{

   public function picture(){
     return view('picture');
   }

   public function uploadFile(Request $request){

     if ($request->input('submit') != null ){

        $file = $request->file('file');

        // File Details
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $tempPath = $file->getRealPath();
        $fileSize = $file->getSize();
        $mimeType = $file->getMimeType();

 //dd($mimeType = $file->getMimeType());


        // Valid File Extensions
        $valid_extension = array("jpg","jpeg","png");



//validate files uploads mimetype

        $rules= [
             'file' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif'
        ];
        $x = $request->all();
        $validator=Validator::make($x, $rules);





 // 2MB in Bytes
 $maxFileSize = 2097152;

        // Check file extension
        if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$valid_extension)){

      // validate mimetype
        if ($validator->passes()){

          // Check file size
          if($fileSize <= $maxFileSize){

             // File upload location
             $location = 'images';

             // Upload file
             $file->move($location,$filename);

             Session::flash('message','Upload Successful.');
          }else{
             Session::flash('message','File too large. File must be less than 2MB.');
          }
//validator starts
}else{
 Session::flash('message','Invalid File type');
}
//validator ends
        }else{
           Session::flash('message','Invalid File Extension1.');
        }

      }

      // Redirect to index
      return redirect()->action('PictureController@picture');
   }
}
```

Comment: Check that the name prop on the input is the same one you validate in your backend.

Comment: here is the input    <input type='file' name='file' >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem with this is the way I was returning the session flash response call. If I echo the response message with `dd()` function as per `dd(....)` it works hence this works now. Since I was working with angularjs, I now return the server response as json call and it works fine... Thanks

```
$rules= [
             'file' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif'
        ];
        $x = $request->all();
        $validator=Validator::make($x, $rules);
        if ($validator->passes()){

dd('File Uploads successful.');
        }else{
         dd('Invalid File type .');

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
            $validate = $request->validate([
            'file' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif'
            ]);
```

instead of :

```
        $rules= [
         'file' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif'
    ];
    $x = $request->all();
    $validator=Validator::make($x, $rules);
```

Comment: at IB. its still the same problem. btw Thanks and welcome to   Stackoverflow